# Using didSelectRowAtIndexPath with UISplitViewController and Google Maps

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, gmsmapview

I am using a UITableViewController inside of a UINavigationController for my Master and I'm using a UIViewController implementing the GMSMapViewDelegate inside of a UINavigationController for my detail side to display a google map. Currently the table view and the Google map are displaying in the UISplitViewController fine.

I am a beginner who recently finished reading Programming in Objective C and Big Nerd Ranch's guide for IOS 7. I can't figure out how to use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to change the camera position with the map. I know how to change the camera position, I've wrote NSLog calls to test whether my app was responding when tapping a particular row, but I can't figure out how to connect the two controllers. I thought about trying to make the controller holding the mapview a delegate for the UITableView, but I am confused as to how to connect the two. What options do I have to carry something like that out.

This is what my appdelegate file looks like.

```
...
mapviewController *mvc = [[mapViewController alloc]init];
locationTableController *ltc = [[locationTableController alloc]init];

UISplitViewController *svc = [[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *sideNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:ltc];
UINavigationController *mapNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mvc];
svc.delegate = mapNav;
svc.viewControllers = @[sideNav,mapNav];
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep your `locationTableController` as delegate and datasource for the table.  You can use `self.splitViewController` to access the splitViewController, your mapNav is then at `viewControllers[1]` and your mapviewcontroller is `rootViewController` of mapNav.  If you implement a `changeCameraPosition` method in your mapviewcontroller, you can call this from within `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.  So in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
UISplitViewController *svc = self.splitViewController;
UINavigationController *mapNav = svc.viewControllers[1];
mapViewController *mvc = (mapViewController *)mapNav.rootViewController;
[mvc changeCameraPosition];
```

You may need to import the relevant .h files if not already done.  Personally I would add some properties to the splitViewController to speed up accessing the other view controllers.

Comment: Excellent. Being a beginner, I didn't know that if a reciever is a child of a split view controller there was a property "splitViewController" that would return the nearest ancestor in the view controller hierarchy. The only difference is I used topViewController once I had access to the mapNav UINavigationController.